# How to extend Active-Active cluster with FreeNAS as shared storage?

Tags: truenas, pacemaker, corosync, shared-storage

I have two physical nodes powered by `Ubuntu` and connected to each other with `Corosync`. And I have the `FreeNAS` server as `NAS`. This `NAS` server mounted on every node - basic scenario.

Now I'm not able to add more HDD/SDD to my NAS. I can't add more space. Run out of free SATA ports and run out of PCI ports to add more ports. "Squeezed all the juices". I see only one solution: run new `NAS` server, mount it on every node, like the first, update app's config on every node to tell about new available path and restart this apps.

I think this is the worst solution possible:

1. Need to stop apps
2. Too much manual stuff

Help me with the best solution in my case please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

simple senario,

if you have 4 HDD in your freenas and they are 2TB disks.

1. replace disk 1 with a 4TB and let it rebuild once 100% complete
2. replace disk 2 with a 4TB and let it rebuild once 100% complete
3. replace disk 3 with a 4TB and let it rebuild once 100% complete
4. replace disk 4 with a 4TB and let it rebuild once 100%
5. expand volume

WIN!